# How to describe accuracy of limited decimals?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let's say I have an answer 2.52 from using a numerical method but also have the analytic solution which is 2.5199. To describe how well they compare would I say the numerical method solution is accurate to two decimals places? It doesn't sound very accurate although we can see that it rather is.

Comment: A relative measure might be more useful, as a difference of 0.0001 is not much in the case of the answer 2.52, but a lot more if the answer were 0.052. So the numerical value deviates from the analytical value by only 0.0001/2.5199 $\approx$ 0.004%.

Answer (score 1):

It is rare that you have both a numeric and analytic solution.  Usually a numeric solution comes with an accuracy bound, so your $2.52$ might be $2.52\pm 0.005$ or some other error bound.  We would default to assuming that error bound from the fact that you only quote two decimals of the analytic solution.  If you have both, you can certainly point out that the analytic solution is much closer to the analytic solution than you would expect.  Sometimes the error bounds on analytic solutions are overestimates and this might lead you to look at the error bounds to see if they can be tightened.  For example, the numeric solution might come from evaluating an infinite series out to some number of terms.  The error bound would come from bounding the sum of all the terms you did not evaluate.  You are allowed to use any bound that is demonstrably larger than the sum, but you might be able to improve the error bound with some more work.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I considered the "value" obtained by the numerical method solution is accurate to 1 decimal place, however, thanks to the note below by Arthur, it is correct to 3 decimal places.

The representation of a positive number $x$ to a precision of $p$ significant digits has a numerical value that is given by the formula (see [Wiki-Significant Figures):](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)
$$\operatorname{Round}\left(\operatorname{abs}\left(x\right)\cdot10^{-\left(\operatorname{floor}\left(\log\ x\right)+1-p\right)}\right)\cdot\left(10\ ^{\left(\operatorname{floor}\left(\log\ x\right)+1-p\right)}\right)$$

For the precision of $2.5199$ to:

$1$ decimal places  = $3$

$2$ decimal places = $2.5$

$3$ decimal places = $2.52$

$4$ decimal places = $2.52$

$5$ decimal places = $2.5199$

Round function in the above context rounds to the next integer, so $Round(1.5)=2$.

One should consider in addition, the effect of using imprecise value when used.

Suppose that you are solving $1000(x- 2.5199)=0$ and you use the value obtained by the numerical method  $x=2.52$ as a root. The answer will be off by $ABS(1000(2.52-2.5199)) =0.1$ Which, depending on your application, may be large.

Other references: [Wiki-Arithmetic Precision](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_precision)

Comment: I'd say it's accurate to 3 decimal places. Sure, the digits aren't all "the right ones", but it's unfair to hold numbers ending in a lot of nines to a different standard than any other number when it comes to what qualifies as "correct to $k$ decimal places".

Comment: @Arthur, thank you for your comment. I did not know that. I know that 0.999...999 =1, however, here there were only 2 9s'. I will correct my answer. I appreciate your soft approach. Thanks to your comment, I found a formula here that I will check: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_precision

Answer (score 0):

You could report the relative error $|2.52 - 2.5199|/|2.5199|$.